# Magento theme, admin issue

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, theme, cpanel

I uploaded my theme package in cpanel file manager `public_html`, and I had this error : `your account is disabled` in Magento admin login page.

I don't know how to unlock it and how to upload theme properly in cpanel to start using my store.

Comment: Can you please explain in more details, have you already a Magento in your server ? it worked before ? and now you have installed a new theme and it doesn't work no more ?

Comment: i just uploaded file in cpanel file manager

Comment: fist time login worked in majento admin,now its not working, majento admin page itself i'm not able to login to go further steps

Comment: Please it's `Magento`and not majento, and what you have copied it's a new theme right ?

Comment: yes it's new theme i bought

Comment: i have account in cpanel

Comment: have you also updated a data base ?

Comment: where i uploaded magento theme package in my domain , after uploading first time i was able to login in admin page of magento, then error started, contacted cpanel and template support ,still stuck with problem.

Comment: I created the database ,its empty nothing there

Comment: no, I'm talking about the second time when you uploaded the files with your new theme, did you also updated the database ?

Comment: yes database updation box was ticked

Comment: Look my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case that you have installed the **Quickstart** instead the theme files, and when you have updated the database maybe the update database script of this quickstart deleted your account from `admin_user` , this is why you can't login.

What you have to do:

1. Note that if you want to install your new theme, it is not necessary to copy the full package `Quickstart`, you just have to copy the files theme in your server and you set this new theme in `Magento admin System > Configuration > Design`
2. Try to clear your cache in `var/cache` and reindexall `shell/ php -f indexer.php reindexall`
3. check in your data if you have your admin login and a password
4. Check your theme DOC and find their password, in general they always put a Demo password.

Good luck.

Comment: hi, I did reinstallation of Magento ,Now I'm able to login in admin page but unable to upload theme in Magento connect manager

Comment: You don't need `Magento connect manager` for that, copy directly the files to your server the files theme and not the quick start

Comment: How do i copy and to which folder or settings?

Comment: https://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-install-magento-theme.html

Comment: where can i find installation root?